# Custom text file not getting generated when executing SOAP tests via batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, soapui

I have a tear down script for my test suite where I am writing pass/fail test cases and steps to a text file. When I execute the test suite via soapui GUI or command line, I am able to see text file getting generated at the desired location. But when I execute batch file which is basically the same code I used for command line, text file is not getting generated.

Code for teardown script for reference.

```
def failedTestCases = 0
def successTestCases = 0
def failedTestSteps = 0
def successTestSteps = 0
def failedAssertions = 0
def successAssertions = 0

File file = new File("C:/tmp/testcase_results_SearchService.txt")
file.text=''
runner.results.each { testCaseResult ->
    def caseName = testCaseResult.testCase.name
        def caseStatus = testCaseResult.status.toString()
        if(caseStatus == 'FAILED'){
             failedTestCases ++
             file << "Test Case: $caseName" + " has failed \n \n"
             }
     else {
        successTestCases ++
        file << "Test Case: $caseName" + " has passed \n \n"}
        // file << "Test Case: $caseName $caseStatus \n" 
     //log.info "Test Case: $caseName $caseStatus" 

     testCaseResult.results.each{ testStepResults ->
        testStepResults.messages.each() { msg -> log.info msg }
        def stepName = testStepResults.testStep.name
        def stepStatus =  testStepResults.status.toString()
        if(stepStatus == 'FAILED'){failedTestSteps ++
        file << "Test Step: $stepName" + " - Fail \n" }
        else{successTestSteps ++
        file << "Test Step: $stepName"+" - Pass \n" }


        if (testStepResults.testStep.config.type == 'request')
        {
            testStepResults.testStep.getAssertionList().each{
                def assertLabel = it.label
                def assertStatus = it.status
                if (assertStatus == 'VALID') { successAssertions ++ }
                else {failedAssertions ++ }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Batch file command:

```
cd C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.4.0\bin\
testrunner.bat -ehttp://SearchService.asmx -r -a -fC:\ABC\Report -s"SearchServiceSoapTS"  -I "C:\Users\ABC\Documents\SearchService_Test.xml"
```

These commands when executed via command line, I am able to see text file getting generated as part of teardown script but not as part of batch file.

Comment: Why does one of the switches have a space between switch and parameter?

Comment: You have not enclosed the path in quotes and moreover there is no space between several switches. You should include the syntax of that command.

Comment: Not a solution, but in the batch file replace `cd` by `cd /D`...